# give id or class to specific layer in revolution slider

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, revolution-slider

I have using revolution slider wordpress plugin.

How can i give `id or class name to specific layer` in perticular slide.

I have using revolution slider 5.0.6 Version.

Can anybody help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select an element to which you want to give an ID and click on Attributes in the menu above (left if Actions and right is Performance). This will open additional menu below where you can enter ID, Classes, Title, Rel, etc.

Other way to do that is to create a new text/html element (add a new layer -> text/html) and manually write your html code - any kind of html is working here.

hope this helps